# How to run script as admin on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, automation, windows-7

I have a case where my users runs a script (bat) file that I wrote on win7 as admin. Im looking for a simple way (without installing any tools) to make a different script that I wrote run on windows start up through this batch file. 
I tried using startup folder but that will run my script without admin rights. I also read about a solution with runas command but it didnt work and also its problematic to know the user details in advanced. I looked online but couldnt find anything to help me to do this automatically through the command line

UPDATE
By looking at the answers im thinking maybe the situation is not clear enough. 
Im writing this script on my pc. I give this script (batch file) to my clients, who lack any knowledge of how to do anything but simple stuffs, such as openning cmd as admin and running my batch file that I write in advance. To sum up, I need this batch to be able to set a process (a different batch or vbs file) to run with admin privelleges on startup of the pc (again, without requiring my clients to do any complicated actions, im hoping to get my script to do everything for them)

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1039156/1138391

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the credentials for the administrator account, you will not be able to run the script with elevated privilege. If you *do* have those credentials, then you can set up a scheduled task (described at [this SevenForums post](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html)), running it under the administrator account.

Check the script carefully, and ensure that it's not incorporating anything that may cause problems, like an unavoidable GUI presentation - [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/848968/task-scheduler-scheduled-task-at-startup-not-working) discusses that pitfall.

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily the "Administrator" account (RID 500). It can be any account in the administrators group.

Comment: @eryksun - In the general case, you're correct, but there have been occasions where we've observed that the -500 account is the only one whose credentials actually work. This may be a matter of group policy in our organization, but I've never been able to actually analyze it fully.

Comment: The default UAC policy excludes the Administrator account (RID 500) from getting logged on with a split standard/elevated token. So an unprivileged `CreateProcessWithLogonW` (e.g. runas.exe) can use this account to start a process with full admin privileges. That's why starting with Vista the default installation also disables this account.

Comment: I dont really see how this answers my question, it requires manual steps to set with task scheduler. All I have is a batch that im writing on aifferent pc that I know that my client will run it with admin priv

Comment: @ZivGlazer, if your batch is run with admin privileges, it can use schtasks.exe to create the task to run at startup, which it can run as SYSTEM, e.g. `schtasks /create /tn [task name] /ru system /sc onstart /tr "absolute\path\to\batch\script"`.

Comment: @eryksun That was exactly what I was looking for and it worked :) I will update with your solution when I get home

Answer (score 1):

Make a shortcut to your batch, set its properties>advanced to run as administrator and then move the shortcut to the startup directory.

Comment: Unless UAC is configured to never notify, this will prompt for consent every time the user logs on.

Comment: Also I need to do it through my batch file, your solution is manual (the setting part). Also the notification is bad, I need it to work on startup without user actions, though if I can configure UAC to never notify through my batch as well then it will be acceptable

Comment: @Magoo Is there any way to bypass the prompt

Comment: @NevinRajVictor: what prompt?

Comment: @Magoo  "Do you want to allow following program to make changes to your computer". If I paste my script alone in start up,it runs but not as administrator. If I create a shortcut to the script and give it admin privilege it doesnt run.If I manually try it they give a pop up with the above prompt

Comment: @NevinRajVictor: No idea, I'm afraid. I automatically disable UAC on my machines, so I never see it.